# Is there any concept to process with multidimensional array such as 10-D array without using 10 'for loops' in C/Java?

Tags: arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

It is true that we have to use **10 'for loops'** for a **10-D array**. But I wonder if there is any other idea to process any dimensional array with less than that much for loops. I need an idea just to get input and print that output for multidimensional array in C/Java. eg: a[3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3]. Please provide some code if possible.

Thank You!

Comment: Have you ever read about SIMD vector processing?

Comment: Why do you need 10 loop ? You iterate through all the items using 2 loop, first start with first row from 1 to 10 columns and continuously do it for 10 rows

Comment: Thank you Jeff for your idea. I will check that. But I need simpler solution.

Comment: Your example of 10 dimensional-array each being 3, gives  3**10 = 59049  entries.
Assuming this was created as a contiguous block of memory or stream of inputs of a specific data type and size you can access all entries with a single loop incrementing the pointer or index to get to the next entry. 
Know as Radix Conversion or Mixed-Radix Conversion
I suggest  understanding Radix Conversion if you want to extract where in your multidimensional array the current index would be.  Here sea search in CS  https://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=radix++Conversion